# Model ignores primary key property

Tags: php, cakephp

**EDIT**

I have modified my table so that my primary key is id, and everything works correctly. Still trying to figure this issue out.

I have the model below that I am using to handle various eav values. The issue that I am seeing is that when I use $Model->save(), it will always try to insert and not update. Even if I set the property/value of the primaryKey.

Event when inserting, I have noticed that I get this query the query below in my logs. The primary key of the table is value_id.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `user_entity_varchars` AS `UserEntityVarchar` 
    WHERE `UserEntityVarchar`.`id` = '1'
```

When I output the debug of the model's structure, this is what I am seeing:

```
[useDbConfig] => default
[useTable] => user_entity_varchars
[displayField] => 
[id] => 
[data] => Array
    (
    )

[table] => user_entity_varchars
[primaryKey] => id
```

For some reason it is not recognizing that the primary key is set in the model class.

This is the model that I am using:

```
<?php
class UserEntityVarchar extends UserAgentAppModel {
var $name = 'UserEntityVarchar';
var $primaryKey = 'value_id';

var $belongsTo = array(
    'UserEntity'=>array(
    'foreignKey' => 'entity_id'
    ));
var $hasOne = array(
    'EavAttribute' => array(
    'foreignKey' => 'attribute_id'
    ));

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you recently update your model or modify the user_entity_varchars table? since cake caches your model, you can try deleting the cache and see if it works. you can find it in tmp/cache/models

Comment: Even with clearing the cache, I have the same issue.

Comment: It's interesting. I never found the time to run it down, but I think I've seen the same thing. Setting `$this->Model->id` still generated a new record while setting `$this->data['Model']['id']` generated the update. I thought I was just misreading something so I went with what worked and forgot to come back to it.

Comment: Can you post your controller code. *Quick hint* make sure you don't have logic that is accidentally calling `$this->Model->create()`

Comment: Are you sure the model file is even loaded? Try adding a die() somewhere in there. Maybe a typo in the file name.

Comment: Are you including the primary key value in the data you are saving?

If it's been populated from a form posting, don't forget to include 

<?php echo $this->Form->input('UserEntityVarchar.id'); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the primaryKey on the model as "value_id", try changing this line to:

```
 <?php
class UserEntityVarchar extends UserAgentAppModel {
var $name = 'UserEntityVarchar';
/*var $primaryKey = 'value_id'; Change this to*/
var $primaryKey = 'id';

var $belongsTo = array(
    'UserEntity'=>array(
    'foreignKey' => 'entity_id'
    ));
var $hasOne = array(
    'EavAttribute' => array(
    'foreignKey' => 'attribute_id'
    ));

}
?>
```

Hope it helps!
cheers

pd, it is my first post!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the data in controller before saving and check whether you are getting the `Id` in post or not.
If you are not getting the `Id` in the post then `model`->`save` will insert and not update.